# Cool class and method names wrapped in ``:  class `This is a cool class` {}?

Tags: scala

I just found some scala code which has a strange class name:

```
 class `This is a cool class` {}
```

and method name:

```
 def `cool method` = {}
```

We can use a sentence for a class or method name!

It's very cool and useful for unit-testing:

```
class UserTest {
   def `user can be saved to db` {
      // testing
   }
}
```

But why we can do this? How to understand it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This feature exists for the sake of interoperability.  If Scala has a reserved word (`with`, for example), then you can still refer to code from other languages which use it as a method or variable or whatever, by using backticks.

Since there was no reason to forbid nearly arbitrary strings, you can use nearly arbitrary strings.

Comment: I have a feeling that the OPs use case may have been considered as well, otherwise only a single symbol would be necessary to denote a quoted identifier much like how C# does it

Comment: @jk. - Only if Scala's lexing works the same way as everyone else's.  The JVM spec allows almost anything as a method name.  I'm not sure whether Scala is smart enough to check both its Java-compatible encoding of symbols (e.g. space becomes $u0020) and the raw version, but it _could_ if someone wrote a language that put non-standard characters in method names.

Comment: @RexKerr ahh yes I was thinking of it too much a Java interop not anything on JVM.

Answer (score 7):

As [@Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr) answered, this feature is for interoperablility. For example,

To call a java method,

```
Thread.yield()
```

you need to write

```
Thread.`yield`()
```

since `yield` is a keyword in scala.

Answer (score 5):

The Scala Language Specification:

> There are three ways to form an identifier. First, an identifier can
>   start with a letter which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of
>   letters and digits. This may be followed by underscore ‘_’ characters
>   and another string composed of either letters and digits or of
>   operator characters. Second, an identifier can start with an operator
>   character followed by an arbitrary sequence of operator characters.
>   The preceding two forms are called plain identifiers. Finally, an
>   identifier may also be formed by an arbitrary string between
>   back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions on which
>   strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of
>   all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Strings wrapped in *`* are valid identifiers in Scala, not only to class names and methods but to functions and variables, too.

Answer (score 1):

To me it is just that the parser and the compiler were built in a way that enables that, so the Scala team implemented it.

I think that it can be cool for a coder to be able to give real names to functions instead of `getThisIncredibleItem` or `get_this_other_item`.

Thanks for your questions which learnt me something new in Scala!